# Only Title shows but message not shown in Sencha alert message box

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new in Sencha,
I try to use message box in my Sencha app for offline/online message, but in message box show only title it not show any message in the message box.
code:

```
 Ext.Msg.show({
            title: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> You are Offline!!!',
            msg: 'Do you want to Save the changes? ',
            multiline: true,
            width: 300
        });
```

looks like:

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the correct property. If you compare [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Msg-method-show), you see that they use `message` property, not `msg`. Also, please note that `multiLine` in the example has a capital L - while yours hasn't.

Comment: Thanks buddy, But I need one more help, Is it possible to close Ext.Msg.show() when the app goes online.

Comment: One more think I try to add custom button using  `buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,buttonText: {OK: 'Retry!!!'},` but it not working.

Comment: @Neotrixs Since `Ext.Msg` is a `singleton`, I would **strongly** advise that you make a custom window if you need custom buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you have any idea for my first question "close Ext.Msg.show()" .

Comment: What is the opposite of `show`? To show sth./to hide sth. -> [`Ext.Msg.hide()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-hide)

Answer (score 1):

Make the correct property in code and you will get the desire result.

Your code should be

```
Ext.Msg.show({
        title: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> You are Offline!!!',
        message: 'Do you want to Save the changes? ', // message
        multiLine: true, // Use camelCase
        width: 300
    });
```

You can see in fiddler [Fidller](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1c5r)